# Parsing data from mysql to json with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

Hi and sorry for my english.

I want to parse data from mysql table to JSON using PHP.
My table have 2 columns: 'reg', 'base' that represents region and base in that region.
Example:

```
reg base
KIE KIE1
KIE KIE2
KIE KIE3
ZYT ZYT1
ZYT ZYT2
CHK CHK1
```

etc

I'm trying to parse this values into JSON that looks like:

```
{"text":"Bases","leaf":false,"children":{"text":"KIE","leaf":false,"children":[{"text":"KIE1","leaf":true},{"text":"KIE2","leaf":true},{"text":"KIE3","leaf":true}]},{"text":"ZYT","leaf":false,"children":[{"text":"ZYT1","leaf":true},{"text":"ZYT2","leaf":true}]},{"text":"CHK","leaf":false,"children":[{"text":"CHK1","leaf":true}]}}
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php
            header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
            $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','test', '123','test');
            $bases = array('text'=>'Bases','leaf'=>false);
            $regions = "select distinct reg from bases";
            $resreg = mysqli_query($conn,$regions);
            while($reg=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resreg)){
                $bases['children'] = array('text'=>$reg['reg'],'leaf'=>false, 'children'=>array());
                $regi = $reg['reg'];
                $query = "select base from bases where reg = '$regi' order by 1";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    $c = array('text'=>$row['base'],'leaf'=>true);
                    $bases['children']['children'][]=$c;
                }
            }
            $d = json_encode($bases);
            echo $d;
            mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

The problem i get values in JSON only from one **reg** and dont get from others

Example:

```
{"text":"Bases","leaf":false,"children":{"text":"KIE","leaf":false,"children":[{"text":"KIE1","leaf":true},{"text":"KIE2","leaf":true},{"text":"KIE3","leaf":true}]}
```

I'm not sure that this is the best metod to get what i want but i'm new to programming.

Can anyone help with this or maybe tell me better way to do this?
I need it for my ExtJs application tree. Thank you.

Comment: You keep overwriting `$bases['children']` with each iteration.  Also you should considering using a JOIN query to get this data rather than running a bunch of queries in nested loops.

Comment: @MikeBrant Yeah thats what i thought.But can you explain it more? Maybe example of query? I really dont get it why i should use query with joins in my case :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some solution:

**list.php**

```
       <?php 
            header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
            $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','test', '123','test');
            $bases = array('text'=>'Bases','leaf'=>false,'children'=>'');
            $regions = "select distinct reg from bases";
            $resreg = mysqli_query($conn,$regions);
            while($reg=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resreg)){
                $bases['children'][] = array('text'=>$reg['reg'],'leaf'=>false,'children'=>'');
            }
            foreach($bases['children'] as $k=>$v){
                $query = "select base from bases where reg = '".$bases['children'][$k]['text']."'";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    $bases['children'][$k]['children'][] = array('text'=>$row['base'],'leaf'=>true);
                }
            }
            $d = json_encode($bases);
            echo $d;
            mysqli_close($conn);
          ?>
```

Did it similiar to [**this**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63389/sql-result-to-json)

Still i think that there is more simple smarter solution.

Anyway, thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

```
while($reg=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resreg)){
                $bases['children'] = array('text'=>$reg['reg'],'leaf'=>false, 'children'=>array());
```

Should be:

```
while($reg=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resreg)){
                $bases['children'][] = array('text'=>$reg['reg'],'leaf'=>false, 'children'=>array());
```

Because now you are adding the `array('text'=>$reg['reg'],'leaf'=>false, 'children'=>array());` to an index of the $bases['children'] array.

Where-as before you were just re-writing `$bases['children']` everytime the while loop ran, therefore it will only equate to the value of the last data assigned to it (the last iteration).

That answers the question of how to get `$bases['children']` to be more than one value, for the 'I don't know if this is the best method' take it to code review.

Comment: Its not working.Output is like


`{"text":"Bases","leaf":false,"children":{"0":{"text":"KIE","leaf":false,"children":[]},"children":[{"text":"KIE1","leaf":true},{"text":"KIE2","leaf":true},{"text":"KIE3","leaf":true},{"text":"KIE4","leaf":true},{"text":"KIE5","leaf":true},{"text":"KIE6","leaf":true},{"text":"KIE7","leaf":true},{"text":"KIE8","leaf":true},{"text":"KIE9","leaf":true},{"text":"ZYT1","leaf":true},...`

Comment: I thought that was the output you wanted? 'The problem i get values in JSON only from one reg and dont get from others' there you go, you have all the values now, you should be more clear on what you want.

Comment: The problem in this case is that bases are not child of region. ie i wanted tree like this:
Bases - Region - Base.
In your case i got: Bases - (Region|Base).
But you're right - i wasn't clear at this point. Sorry